# Java ClassFile additional byte?

Tags: java, jvm, .class-file

I read about Java ClassFile and I have tried to understand every byte in it. Basically everything is clear besides one thing... Just after the method definition (Code attribute) there is SourceFile attribute. But before that there is additional byte.

Hello.java

```java
public class Hello {    
}
```

Hello.class

```
CA FE BA BE 00 00 00 34 00 0D 0A 00 03 00 0A 07 00 0B 07
00 0C 01 00 06 3C 69 6E 69 74 3E 01 00 03 28 29 56 01 00 
04 43 6F 64 65 01 00 0F 4C 69 6E 65 4E 75 6D 62 65 72 54 
61 62 6C 65 01 00 0A 53 6F 75 72 63 65 46 69 6C 65 01 00 
0A 48 65 6C 6C 6F 2E 6A 61 76 61 0C 00 04 00 05 01 00 05 
48 65 6C 6C 6F 01 00 10 6A 61 76 61 2F 6C 61 6E 67 2F 4F 
62 6A 65 63 74 00 21 00 02 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 
00 04 00 05 00 01 00 06 00 00 00 1D 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 
05 2A B7 00 01 B1 00 00 00 01 00 07 00 00 00 06 00 01 00 
00 00 01 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 02 00 09
```

We are interested in following bytes: (These are last ones)

```
Code attribute        06 00 00 00 1D 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 05 2A B7 00 01 B1 00
                      00 00 01 00 07 00 00 00 06 00 01 00 00 00 01

What are these?       00 01 
SourceFile attribute  00 08 00 00 00 02 00 09
```

I analyzed data of Code attribute according to [Code Attribute doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3)

Comment: The previous comment is right, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file, it is the attribute count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `attributes_count`.

> The value of the `attributes_count` item indicates the number of attributes of the Code attribute.

Sources:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file